# Stripe payment gateway not accepting Visa /Master Debit Card

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I have integrated Stripe payment simple checkout in PHP as mentioned in this [Link](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-simple). I am able to process credit cards. However, when I am trying to process VISA/Master debit card it says `Card Declined`. The bank account used in Stripe is USA, and card from India. When I talked to stripe they say they are not declining it and I need to call local debit card holder's bank which I did and they said it should be processed. I even tried with an International shopping debit card.

My code :

```
 <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="pk_live_************************"
    data-amount="<?php echo $stripeamount;?>"
    data-name="KAEM Technologies USA, Inc"
    data-email="<?php echo $email;?>"
    data-currency="<?php echo $curr; ?>"
    data-description="Widget"
    data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
    data-locale="auto">
                            
</script>
```

Error code `402` on stripe :

```
{
  "error": {
  "charge": "ch_*************************",
  "code": "card_declined",
  "decline_code": "do_not_honor",
  "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/card-declined",
  "message": "Your card was declined.",
  "type": "card_error"
}
}
```

So, if anyone has done debit card integration do let e know, I am stuck between the stripe and the bank.

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this really isn't a question about code. The bank is declining the charge here and your customer needs to talk to their bank.

Comment: I dont know where to ask this, I thought I might have to make some code changes and also seeking advice from anyone here might have done that.So please guide e towards right place . Thanks

Comment: You should talk to Stripe's support team really: https://support.stripe.com/contact